# Java compiler won't find methods from another Java file in same folder?

Tags: java, methods

Our Assignment was to take the code our instructor gave us, and write the methods that that code calls in a separate java file. After that, we're supposed to put it in the same folder. Here is the code he gave us:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSCD210Lab9
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      String name = null;
      double height, weight;

      do
      {
         name = Lab9Methods.readName(kb);
         height = Lab9Methods.readInfo(kb, "height");
         weight = Lab9Methods.readInfo("weight", kb);
         Lab9Methods.displayResults(name, height, weight, Lab9Methods.calcBMI(height, weight));

      }while(Lab9Methods.goAgain(kb)); 

   }// end main

}// end class
```

I've compiled the file that I wrote the methods in, and it compiles fine, no errors at all. However, when I go to compile this code right after, the compiler points to every instance where Lab9Methods is written, and it gives the error "error: cannot find symbol".

I don't understand why it won't read the methods from the other file, even though both files are in the same folder. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for my Lab9Methods class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab9Methods
{



      public static String readName(final Scanner kb)throws Exception 
      {
      if(kb == null)
         throw new RuntimeException("Precondition not met");

         String name;
         System.out.println("Please enter the person's name: ");
         name = kb.nextLine();

         return name;    
      }


      public static double readInfo(final Scanner kb, final String str)
      {

      System.out.println("Please enter your" + str + ";");

      double height = kb.nextDouble();

      return height; 
      }


      public static double readInfo(final String str ,final Scanner kb)
      {


      System.out.println("Please enter your" + str + ";");
      double weight = readInfo(kb,str);

      return weight;

      }

      public static int calcBMI(double height, double weight)
      {
      int calcBMI = (int)(weight/((height * height) * 703));

      return calcBMI ;


      }


      public static void displayResults(final String name, final double height, final double weight, final double bmi)
      {

      System.out.println(name + "with a weight of" + weight + "and a height of" + height + " " + bmi);
      if(bmi < 18.5)
      { 
        System.out.println("You are underweight");
      }
      else if(bmi > 18.6 && bmi < 24.9)
      {  
        System.out.println("You are normal");
      }
      else if(bmi > 25.1 && bmi < 29.9)
      {
        System.out.println("You are overweight");
      }
      else if(bmi > 29.9)
      {
        System.out.println("You are obese");
      }        
    }

    public static boolean goAgain(final Scanner kb)
    {
        boolean goAgain = false;
        String answer;
        System.out.println("Do you want to go again (Yes/No) :");
        answer = kb.nextLine();

        while(!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no"))
        {
         System.out.print("Error re-try, Do you want to go again (Yes/No) :");
         answer = kb.nextLine();
        }
        if(answer.equals("yes"))
        { 
         goAgain = true; 
        }
        else if(answer.equals("no"))
        {
         goAgain = false;
        }
        return goAgain;
    }    

 }
```

Comment: if possible, can you post Lab9Methods class structure as well.

Comment: Yes, I'll get right on that.

Comment: Now, can you also add the command you used to compile and to run. and your working directory from where you executed the command and the directory where your class files were created/source was .

Comment: I compiled both of them in the JGrasp IDE, and they're both in a folder with the file path "C:\Users\kcollins\Desktop\New folder" minus the quotes.

Comment: your code looks okay to me. I believe its problem with IDE or configuration related to IDE. How about you keep both files in a folder, you change your working directory to that folder, and compile  both files  and run your main using command line.

Comment: for reference, to compile , you can user : javac *.java , after you run this command , there should be .class file generated for both of your java file. then you can run applicaiton using : java CSCD210Lab9

Comment: What is the name of the file containing the Lab9Methods class??

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading an IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ community edition for example) and doing the project in that.  My guess is you need to declare the 'package' which should map to the directory your classes are in.

And tell your tutor his style more C than Java, and that //end main and //end class went out of fashion a long time ago ;)

Comment: Haha I agree, but he is one of those "Old Generation" style teachers. And I'm compiling these files in an IDE by the way. JGrasp.

Comment: If you don't declare the package, you get the default one (which maps to the current directory during compile and run).  Neither class declares one, so as long as they're in the same directory, they're in the same package.